# Transfer user's input between JavaScript files in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

This issue is a kind of specific one. So, I'll try to be as thorough as possible.

I am making this in trying to learn how to make Chrome extensions that can interact with websites.

What this is supposed to do is take the input of the input field, which is whatever the user writes in, then replace a specific part of a website with that text. I am using the 'Simple one-time requests' described in [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging), because it has an ID and is easy to edit via `getElementById`.

Simply replacing the 'Simple one-time request' sentence on button click is easy, but problems arise when I try to get the user's input and insert it into the document.

Here is my code:

*manifest.json*:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "document-editor-test",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "cookies",
      "storage"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Site Text Editor",
      "default_popup": "menu.html"
  }
}
```

*content.js*:

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    var inputText = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var theValue = inputText;
    chrome.storage.local.set({'value': theValue}, function(){
        message('value saved');
    });
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({ file: 'replace.js' })
}, false);
```

*replace.js*:

```
var item = chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(){
    message('Value gotten')
})
document.getElementById('simple').innerHTML = item;
```

*menu.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <style>
        body {width: 200px;}
        #text{ font-size: 13px; text-align: center;}
    </style>

    <body>
        <input id='input' type="text" placeholder="Text Here">
        <button id='button' class='button button'>Ok</button>
        <script src="content.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I try to use an easy storage script to save the value and parse it via the file, but it only makes the script print out `undefined`.

What is the solution to passing the input value to the document?

Comment: Regarding how you are trying to use `chrome.storage.local.get()`, please see: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Answer (score 1):

1. The extension popup is a different page, not related to the web page opened in a tab: your popup script name is misleading/wrong: it's not a content script, rename it to e.g. `menu.js`
2. Chrome API methods that accept function callbacks are [*asynchronous*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index#conventions) and return the value inside the function callback. Check with the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) to see the possible parameters.

   `chrome.storage.local.get` in your content script is invoked incorrectly so it returns `undefined` by design, specify the key name and use the value inside a callback instead:

   ```
   var item;

   chrome.storage.local.get('value', function(data) {
       item = data.value;
       document.getElementById('simple').innerHTML = item;
   });
   ```
3. Your code in the popup might cause a race condition in the asynchronous API so the content script gets injected before the value is saved (theoretically possible). Chain the calls by nesting:

   ```
   chrome.storage.local.set({'value': theValue}, function() {
       message('value saved');
       chrome.tabs.executeScript({ file: 'replace.js' });
   });
   ```